# JSON SelectToken Path Either Too High (Parent) or Too Low (Child) For Values I Want

Tags: c#, .net, json.net, jsonpath

I'm querying the DellAPI at https://sandbox.api.dell.com/support/assetinfo/v4/ to get the end date of extended onsite support warranties as a .NET object. But I'm having trouble defining my SelectToken path to work with the JSON result from Dell.

Here's the relevant bit of code I'm using (sans the dellAPIKey and Service Tag):

```
string Serial = device.dev_service_tag_serial;
var json = new WebClient().DownloadString(dellAPIPath + "getassetwarranty/" + Serial + "?apikey=" + dellAPIKey);
JObject jo = JObject.Parse(json);

foreach (JProperty x in jo.SelectToken("AssetWarrantyResponse[0].AssetEntitlementData"))
{
    JToken servicelevel = x.Value.SelectToken("ServiceLevelDescription");
    string servicelevelStr = servicelevel.ToString().ToLower();
    JToken entitlementtype = x.Value.SelectToken("EntitlementType");
    string entitlementtypeStr = entitlementtype.ToString().ToLower();

    if (servicelevelStr.Contains("onsite") && entitlementtypeStr.Contains("extended"))
    {
        JToken enddate = x.Value.SelectToken("EndDate");
        string enddateStr = enddate.ToString();
        device.dev_warranty_exp = DateTime.Parse(enddateStr);

    }

}
```

The very first SelectToken either returns NULL, or the wrong level of token, depending on how I change it.

Here is one result of the Dell API JSON results I am working with (with potentially sensitive values replaced with Ones for numbers and As for letters):

```
{{
  "AssetWarrantyResponse": [
    {
      "AssetHeaderData": {
        "BUID": "11",
        "ServiceTag": "11A11A1",
        "ShipDate": "2011-03-02T00:00:00",
        "CountryLookupCode": "US",
        "LocalChannel": "45",
        "CustomerNumber": "1111111",
        "ItemClassCode": "2N002",
        "IsDuplicate": false,
        "MachineDescription": "Latitude E6510",
        "OrderNumber": "111111111",
        "ParentServiceTag": null
      },
      "ProductHeaderData": {
        "SystemDescription": "Latitude E6510",
        "ProductId": "latitude-e6510",
        "ProductFamily": "Laptops",
        "LOB": "Latitude",
        "LOBFriendlyName": "Latitude"
      },
      "AssetEntitlementData": [
        {
          "StartDate": "2011-03-02T00:00:00",
          "EndDate": "2015-03-02T23:59:59",
          "ServiceLevelDescription": "Complete Care / Accidental Damage",
          "ServiceLevelCode": "CC",
          "ServiceLevelGroup": 11,
          "EntitlementType": "INITIAL",
          "ServiceProvider": "DELL",
          "ItemNumber": "908-5233"
        },
        {
          "StartDate": "2012-03-03T00:00:00",
          "EndDate": "2015-03-02T23:59:59",
          "ServiceLevelDescription": "ProSupport",
          "ServiceLevelCode": "TS",
          "ServiceLevelGroup": 8,
          "EntitlementType": "EXTENDED",
          "ServiceProvider": "DELL",
          "ItemNumber": "981-1533"
        },
        {
          "StartDate": "2012-03-03T00:00:00",
          "EndDate": "2015-03-02T23:59:59",
          "ServiceLevelDescription": "Onsite Service After Remote Diagnosis (Consumer Customer)/ Next Business Day Onsite After Remote Diagnosis (Commercial Customer)",
          "ServiceLevelCode": "ND",
          "ServiceLevelGroup": 5,
          "EntitlementType": "EXTENDED",
          "ServiceProvider": "QLX",
          "ItemNumber": "908-5163"
        },
        {
          "StartDate": "2011-03-02T00:00:00",
          "EndDate": "2012-03-02T23:59:59",
          "ServiceLevelDescription": "ProSupport",
          "ServiceLevelCode": "TS",
          "ServiceLevelGroup": 8,
          "EntitlementType": "INITIAL",
          "ServiceProvider": "DELL",
          "ItemNumber": "984-4000"
        },
        {
          "StartDate": "2011-03-02T00:00:00",
          "EndDate": "2012-03-02T23:59:59",
          "ServiceLevelDescription": "Onsite Service After Remote Diagnosis (Consumer Customer)/ Next Business Day Onsite After Remote Diagnosis (Commercial Customer)",
          "ServiceLevelCode": "ND",
          "ServiceLevelGroup": 5,
          "EntitlementType": "INITIAL",
          "ServiceProvider": "QLX",
          "ItemNumber": "926-2550"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "InvalidFormatAssets": {
    "BadAssets": []
  },
  "InvalidBILAssets": {
    "BadAssets": []
  },
  "ExcessTags": {
    "BadAssets": []
  },
  "AdditionalInformation": null
}}
```

All I care about is the AssetEntitlementData bit. For the one with a service level containing "onsite" and entitlement type containing "extended" I want to return the EndDate value.

Can anybody steer me in the right direction as to where I am going wrong with the jo.SelectToken path?

Comment: If you are trying to get something "as a NET object" then you should deserialize, not parse

Comment: `AssetEntitlementData` is an array not an object.

Comment: @Plutonix Maybe ".NET object" was the wrong term. My end goal is to take the EndDate value from the API (after filtering) and populate a field (device.dev_warranty_exp) in my ASP.NET Core MVC model.

Comment: Thats also incomplete/invalid JSON.  You may have edited for brevity but that works against providing a [mcve]

Comment: @Plutonix Thank you for the guidance. I've posted the entire Dell API result for a single service tag.

Comment: @dbc Thank you! I'm frustratingly new to JSON so that is very helpful information. This gives me more fuel for my search.

Comment: `var date = DateTime.Parse(jobj["AssetWarrantyResponse"][0]["AssetEntitlementData"][0]["EndDate"].ToString());` Loop thru  the `AssetEntitlementData` array to get the others...deserializing would still be easier

Comment: @Plutonix Thanks, I am now looking into deserializing. I appreciate all your help.

Comment: @Plutonix You wouldn't happen to have a quick example of how I would go about looping through the `AssetEntitlementData` array in the way you described, would you? I'd like to see this folly through before I start fresh with a deserialziation re-write.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the `EndDate` it seems like you need to know the `ItemNumber` so you know the computer related to that Service Level and Date.  So thats at least 3 pieces of information.

Getting the data from Parsing is fairly simple, if convoluted syntax:

```
var jobj = JObject.Parse(jstr);

//isolate the data group for shorter code
var jAssets = jobj["AssetWarrantyResponse"][0]["AssetEntitlementData"];  
// how many    
int assetCt = jAssets.Count();

for (int k = 0; k < assetCt; k++)
{ 
    Console.WriteLine("Item Number: {0}, End Date: {1}, Svc Lvl: {2}",
        jAssets[k]["ItemNumber"],
        DateTime.Parse(jAssets[k]["EndDate"].ToString()),
        jAssets[k]["ServiceLevelDescription"]);      
}
```

Sample result:

> Item Number: 908-5233, End Date: 3/9/2015 11:59:59 PM, Svc Lvl: Complete Care / Accidental Damage
> Item Number: 981-1533, End Date: 3/7/2015 11:59:59 PM, Svc Lvl: ProSupport
> Item Number: 908-5163, End Date: 3/20/2015 11:59:59 PM, Svc Lvl: Onsite Service After Remote Diagnosis (Consumer Customer)/ Next Business Day Onsite After  Remote Diagnosis (Commercial Customer)

- I changed some dates so I could be sure it was picking up different ones
- Filtering to just the one you want (only one there is EXTENDED and OnSite) still needs to be done.  That is easier with NET objects and Deserializing.

#### Deserializing

Given a class representing the `AssetEntitlementData`:

```
public class DellData
{
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public string ServiceLevelDescription { get; set; }
    public string ServiceLevelCode { get; set; }
    public int ServiceLevelGroup { get; set; }
    public string EntitlementType { get; set; }
    public string ServiceProvider { get; set; }
    public string ItemNumber { get; set; }
}
```

You can parse out that chunk and get it into a *filtered* `List<DellData>`:

```
var jobj = JObject.Parse(jstr);

// deserialize and filter to just the ones you want:
List<DellData> data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<DellData>>(jAssets.ToString()).
            Where( k => (k.ServiceLevelGroup == 5) && (k.EntitlementType == "EXTENDED")).
            ToList();
```

Note that rather than looking for particular text, this looks for a `ServiceLevelGroup` of 5 so if they change the descriptions ("On-Site" or "Onsite service excluded") your code doesn't break.  Print the results:

```
foreach (DellData d in data)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Item Number: {0}, End Date: {1}, Svc Grp: {2}",
        d.ItemNumber,
        d.EndDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"),
        d.ServiceLevelGroup);
}
```

Results:

> Item Number: 867-5309, End Date: 2017-03-26, Svc Grp: 5
> Item Number: 908-5163, End Date: 2015-03-20, Svc Grp: 5

I added an additional item matching the criteria because a sample of one is feeble.

Comment: This is fantastic and easy to understand. Thank you! I'm trying to work out how `jAssets` works in the deserializing example though (does not exist in current context).

Comment: Its the same as in the first block:  `var jAssets = jobj["AssetWarrantyResponse"][0]["AssetEntitlementData"]; `

Comment: I'm in your debt. Thanks for the lessons!

Comment: Note that you can omit any properties from DellData that you truly have no need for